# Array of strings gets scrambled after exiting strtok loop - C

Tags: c, file, multidimensional-array, char, strtok

I have a text file like this:

```
word 1;word 2;word 3;word 4
word 5;word 6;word 7;word 8
word 9;word 10;word 11;word 12
word 13;word 14;word 15;word 16
```

And I want to export this file into a 2d string array in C. Here is my code:

```
char* orders[LineCounter][4];
int i = 0, j;
f = fopen("test.txt","r");
printf("Inside the loop\n");
while (getline(&line, &len, f) != -1) {
    j = 0;
    char* token = strtok(line,";\n");
    while (token != NULL){
          orders[i][j] = token;
          printf("%s\n", orders[i][j]);
          token = strtok(NULL,";\n");
          j++;
    }
    i++;     
}
printf("\n\nOutside the loop\n");
    for (int k=0;k<LineCounter;k++){
        for (int l=0;l<4;l++){
            printf("%s ", orders[k][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
```

As you can see I print the contents of the array two times. One time while inside the strtok loop and one time after the everything is finished. The first time everything is printed fine but when I print the array after the I am done parsing the file, the contents are scrambled like this:

```
Inside the loop

word 1
word 2
word 3
word 4
word 5
word 6
word 7
word 8
word 9
word 10
word 11
word 12
word 13
word 14
word 15
word 16


Outside the loop
word 13  4 15 
word 13  4 15 
word 13    
word 13 word 14 word 15 word 16
```

As you can see part of the content is empty or the "word" is cut off. Am I missing something?

Comment: `orders[i][j] = token;`-->> `orders[i][j] = strdup(token);`

Comment: @wildplasser That fixed it, thanks a lot. But can you explain the mistake to me?

Comment: `getline(&line` - strtok operates on `line`. It does not have itself memory, it operates on `line`. It overwrites `line` and returns pointers to `line`. If you read the next `line`, the last one is invalid. You have to duplicate memory.

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh I understand now. Thanks for the explanation.